# how to compare elements in the same array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am now trying to make a method for a website that compares elements within a json array of objects for example:

```json
[
    {
        course code: act 227,
        course name:science,
        section:12345,
        statues:closed, 
        day : 1 3 5,
        time:8 AM-9AM, 
        finale date: 
        3/4/2023
    }, 
    {
        course code: mat 147,
        course name:scince,
        section:12346,
        statues:open,
        day:2 4,
        time:11AM-12AM, 
        finale date: 3/6/2023
    },
    // ...
]
```

and so on,

this array is very long as there are a lot of repeated courses with different sections and time.

my idea is that the user enters his wanted course codes in a table in the course code column and this method will compare between the days and times of the entered courses and finale dates so that there would be no conflict then it will dynamically fills the cells of the rest of the data. for example the user entered these information:

| course code | course name | section | status | day | time | finale date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| act227 | - | - | - | - | - | - |
| mat147 | - | - | - | - | - | - |

the user can add as many sections as he wants but the most important thing is that after he clicks on the button the table is supposed to be like this:

| course code | course name | section | status | day | time | finale date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| act227 | science | 12345 | close | 1 3 5 | 8 AM-9AM | 3/4/2023 |
| mat147 | math | 12346 | open | 2 4 | 11AM-12AM | 3/6/2023 |

and this wanted method can generate multiple schedules that the user can view and choose if there are many sections that coincide in their times.

I've tried searching the web so many times but I only found how to compare between tow arrays or an array but with a different format so if you can help I would be so thankful.

Comment: *"a keyed json array of objects for example: ..."*: that is not valid JSON, nor valid JavaScript

Comment: It is very hard to understand the requirement. please reformat and rephrase

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use loops to compare each course with other course to check if conflicts then generates all possible schedules that don't have conflicts and returns them

```js
function generateSchedule(courseCodes) {
  const courses = [
    {courseCode: "kareem-123", courseName: "science", section: "12345", status: "closed", day: "1 3 5", time: "8 AM-9AM", finaleDate: "3/4/2023"},
    {courseCode: "kareem-1234", courseName: "math", section: "12346", status: "open", day: "2 4", time: "11AM-12AM", finaleDate: "3/6/2023"},
  ];

  const filteredCourses = courses.filter(course => courseCodes.includes(course.courseCode));

  // create all possible schedules that don't have conflicts
  const schedules = [[]];
  filteredCourses.forEach(course => {
    const newSchedules = [];
    schedules.forEach(schedule => {
      // Check if the course conflicts with any courses already in the schedule
      const conflict = schedule.some(scheduledCourse => {
        const daysOverlap = scheduledCourse.day.split(" ").some(day => course.day.split(" ").includes(day));
        const timesOverlap = scheduledCourse.time === course.time;
        const finaleDatesOverlap = scheduledCourse.finaleDate === course.finaleDate;

        return daysOverlap && timesOverlap && finaleDatesOverlap;
      });

      if (!conflict) {
        // No conflict, add course to the schedule
        newSchedules.push([...schedule, course]);
      }
    });
    schedules.push(...newSchedules);
  });

  return schedules.filter(schedule => schedule.length === filteredCourses.length);
}

const coursesCodes = ["kareem-123", "kareem-1234"];
const schedules = generateSchedule(coursesCodes);
console.log(schedules);
```